# content type not supported json

Tags: php, json, curl

i am making an api call with the following code to docusign to delete a recipient:

```
$data = "{
\"signers\": [{
\"recipientId\": \"1\"
}]
}";  

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."\r\n";


$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/$accountId/envelopes/$envelopeId/recipients";


$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
  "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl); 
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);


$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
  echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
  print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
  exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

i am getting the following error : error calling webservice, status is:400 error text is --> { "errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE", "message": "Content Type specified is not supported." }. Thanks

Comment: It's never good to manually build your own json. `$data = json_encode(array('signers' => array('recipientId' => 1)));`

Comment: Why are you wrapping the HTTP request body in a `multipart/` container?

Comment: If you give curl an array as the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` value it will generate a `multipart/form-data` request automatically. Why don't you let it do its thing instead of trying to do it by hand?

Comment: ok i have changed my code like this: $data_recipient = json_encode(array('signers' => array('recipientId' => 1)));curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_recipient),
  "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);        but i am still getting an error - The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object